# How to collect all properties of an object that has been updated?

Tags: java

I'm kind of new to java, so my apologies if you find this question senseless.
Just want to ask if it's possible to collect all the properties of an object, specifically those that are no longer the default value. For example, a bean where some properties have been set to new values, how will I be able to get those properties that were updated given only the object with the new values in it..
Or is there a way to collect all the setter methods that were called for that given bean?

Comment: Do you have one particular bean in which you want to detect and act-upon non-default attribute values; OR do you need to do this "generically" for many beans? The approach I'd take would be different, because the generic solution is a lot harder.

Answer (score 4):

You can register a [`java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) in your object and fire an event when each setter is invoked. It would look like:

```
public class Foo {
   // some field here
   private PropertyChangeListener listener;

   public void setBar(String bar) {
      this.bar = bar;
      if (listener != null) {
         listener.fireEvent(..);
      }
   }
   // etc setters and getters

   // setter for the listener
   // (instead of a single listener, you may want a collection of listeners)
}
```

Then in the listener you can store all changes in a collection, for example.

Comment: +1 for the standard way (even though it is complicated as hell)

Comment: as far as I understood, catching changes while they occur wasn't the question

Comment: no, but he wants to know which properties were changed. That's why, on each change, he can add the changed properties to a collection (my last paragraph)

Comment: hmm ... that's collecting those changed _after_ s/he starts listening. The requirement was "those properties that were updated given only the object with the new values in it." - that's _before_ s/he has a chance to start listening

Comment: I assume that when he creates the object, he can register the listener as well.

Answer (score 1):

On any "bean", that is a class playing by the bean spec, you can use introspection/reflection, something like:

```
public static class MyBean {

    String myName;

    public MyBean() {
       this(null);
    }

    public MyBean(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return myName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.myName = name;
    }
}

public void testBeanProperties() throws Exception {
    Object bean = new MyBean("myName");
    compareProperties(bean);
}

private void compareProperties(Object bean) throws Exception {
    BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean.getClass()); 
    Object defaultInstance = bean.getClass().newInstance();
    PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
    for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : descriptors) {
        Object defaultValue = getValue(defaultInstance, descriptor);
        Object myValue = getValue(bean, descriptor);
        if (!areEqual(myValue, defaultValue)) {
            System.out.println("default/changed: " + defaultValue + " / " + myValue );
        }
    }
}

public Object getValue(Object bean, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) throws Exception {
    Method getter = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
    if (getter != null)
        return getter.invoke(bean, (Object[]) null);
    return null;
}
```

as to the answers involving a PropertyChangeListener: that's an option only if the "bean" actually fires any change notification (which it should, but that's another topic :-) Also, it can't catch any properties set in a constructor.

Comment: it's a nice way to track changes, though it involves a creation of a new object, and reflection. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default baked-in way for achieving it. If I understand well, you want to collect all the properties that have been modified in a bean. Something like:

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
bean.setName("john");
List modified = bean.getModifiedFields();
```

As Bohzo suggested you can use a PropertyChangeListener to fire an event when a property gets modified or, more simply:

```
public class MyBean {
   private Map<String, Object> modifiedValuesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   private String name;
   public void setName(String _name) {
     name = _name;
     modifiedValuesMap.put("name", _name);

   }      
   public Map<String, Object> getModifiedValues() {
     return modifiedValuesMap;
   }

}
```